# View not refreshing when Core Data are updated via another function

Tags: swiftui

EDIT: added more context
I have a List in the ContentView which shows a list of Core Data items. In the list I call the function that should show if one of those items has a "check" that day ( imagine a checklist app ).
The statusView works ok when it loads but it does not refresh when , from a button on the ContentView I create an entry that should effect the fetchRequest.
What I am doing wrong?
This is the statusView:

```
struct statusView: View {
    
    @FetchRequest var fetchRequest: FetchedResults<Check>
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    
    var body: some View {

        if(fetchRequest.count > 0 ) {
            Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                                .imageScale(.large)
                                .font(.title2)
                                .foregroundColor(Color(.sRGB, red: 91/255, green: 200/255, blue: 175/255))
        } else {
            Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.circle")
                                .imageScale(.large)
                                .font(.title2)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
        }
    }
    
    init(filter: String) {
        let p1 = NSPredicate(format: "habit_id == %@", filter)
        let p2 = NSPredicate(format: "date >= %@ && date <= %@", Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date()) as CVarArg, Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date() + 86400) as CVarArg)
        let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [p1, p2])
        _fetchRequest = FetchRequest<Check>(sortDescriptors: [], predicate: predicate)
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/YY"
    }
    
}
```

and this is the ContentView that is calling the statusView

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var habits: FetchedResults<Habit>
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var checks: FetchedResults<Check>
    
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var todayChecks: FetchedResults<Check>
    
    
    @State private var thisID: String = ""
    @State private var selection: String? = nil
    @State private var title = ""
    @State private var forceRefresh = ""
    var color_purple: Color = Color(.sRGB, red: 161/255, green: 78/255, blue: 191/255)
    
    func createCheckToday(habit_id: UUID) {
        
        let new_check = Check(context: moc)
        new_check.id = UUID()
        new_check.date = Date()
        new_check.habit_id = habit_id
        try? moc.save()

    }
    
    func deleteHabit(obj: NSManagedObject) {
        moc.delete(obj)
        try! moc.save()
    }
    
    func _riga(title: String, subtitle: String, id: UUID, obj: NSManagedObject) -> some View {
        print(id.uuidString)
        var body: some View {
            Button {
                createCheckToday(habit_id: id)
            } label: {
                HStack {
                    //statusView(filter: id.uuidString)
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                      Text(title)
                        .font(.headline)
                      Text(subtitle)
                        .font(.subheadline)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        return body
    }
    
    func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        // delete the objects here
    }
    
    var body: some View {
         
        NavigationView {
            
            VStack {
            Text("")
                    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                            HStack {
                                Image(systemName: "note")
                                    .imageScale(.large)
                                    .font(.title2)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(.sRGB, red: 161/255, green: 78/255, blue: 191/255))
                                Text("Habit-o")
                                    .font(Font.system(.largeTitle, design: .rounded).weight(.heavy))
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(.sRGB, red: 161/255, green: 78/255, blue: 191/255))
                                    .padding(10)
                            }
                        }
                    }
            //---
            List(habits) { habit in
                HStack {
                    statusView(filter: habit.id!.uuidString)
                    _riga(title: habit.title!, subtitle: habit.subtitle!, id: habit.id!, obj: habit)
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            Spacer()
            //---
            NavigationLink(destination: newForm(), tag: "A", selection: $selection) { EmptyView() }
            Button(action: {
                selection="A"
            }) {
                Text("New Habit")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .padding()
                .background(color_purple)
                .cornerRadius(40)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .padding(10)
                .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 40)
                            .stroke(Color.purple, lineWidth: 5)
                    )
                
                
            }
            
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            
        }
    //---->
    }
    
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: "The statusView works ok when it loads", both with and without matching data?

Comment: When I relaunch the app the statusView gets the updated data.

Comment: All CoreData objects should be wrapped in ObservedObject to see changes.

Comment: @loremipsum can you point me in the right direction on this?

Comment: You haven’t provided a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so there is no way to help you specifically the wrapper is because all CoreData objects are ObservableObjects the FetchRequest doesn’t get rerun just because you change a variable, you are supposed to be observing those changes with The wrapper. There is a big difference when you choose reference objects instead of value objects. Minimal means minimal, you should provide the least amount of code in the most simple way possible use the basic “Item” in a clean project.

Comment: @loremipsum you are right. I added now the ContentView from which the statusView is called. :)

Comment: There is still way too much going on and you haven’t even explained exactly what isn’t working, what function? Put this code into a clean project and simplify it. But a quicker way might be to just get rid of the fetch request in the second view. Your predicate includes id therefore you will only ever get one habit. Why not just pass the habit from the list? Then you can just check if the date is today.

Comment: I agree, in the first view there is stuff not relevant to the issue. I need to have a second fetchRequest cos in the ContentView I get the list of Habits and with statusView ( passing in the habit id ) i get whether there is a check for the specific day ( today ). They are two separated entity: habit and check.